# how to upload files from a FTP location into Marklogic

Tags: upload, ftp, filesystems, marklogic

i need to upload files from a FTP location into marklogic. please guide me on this

Answer (score 4):

MarkLogic doesn't allow accessing external `FTP` locations from `XQuery`, like it allows `HTTP` calls. Nor does it provide `FTP` servers, like it provides `WebDAV` servers.

You can however easily put a mediator in between that accesses the `FTP` instead, and use other means to upload the document into MarkLogic. The latter can be done through a `WebDAV` App Server that you can create using the Admin interface, through the `built-in` REST api in MarkLogic 6 ( http://docs.marklogic.com/REST ), or through custom code like Corona ( http://developer.marklogic.com/code/corona ).

If you write the mediator in Java, you can also use the `Java API` ( see Java API tab at http://docs.marklogic.com/ ).

HTH!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use MLJAM to execute Java code from MarkLogic, or simply call a custom webservice of your own that serves as proxy to retrieve the files from FTP..

Answer (score 0):

I personally would avoid `WebDav` unless you absolutely need it.
Is this a one-off, batch , or continous job ?

If one-off or batch then I would suggest using a script to `FTP` the files to a local disk then using `mlcp` or `RecordLoader` or `xmlsh` to push them to MarkLogic.

If this is a continuous job then a custom Java app is probably the way to go.
Do realize that `FTP` is a *horribly sensitive* protocol .. it can fail in so many ways and takes special port openings etc.  It was designed in the 80's before firewalls, NAT and such.
Getting FTP to work reliably irregardless of MarkLogic is a black magic art in itself.

If its possible to use another protocol then `FTP` that would be ideal.
Say `scp` or `rsync` or `http`.

Answer (score 0):

We have a app that needs documents from a shared folder that we running an etl on to get into marklogic. You can do this a number of ways. If you are able to I'd amount the drive on the marklogic box and then read from there. IF that doesnt work see if you can make those files viewable from an http-get requested. IF that doest work then you might want to make a web services.